# ReactJS: How do I go the next page after condition is true?

Tags: reactjs

After the conditions are met how does it automatically redirect to next page?

```
handleSubmit = event => {
     event.preventDefault();
        const { data } = this.state
        const tabletopModel = data['token']
        const newData = tabletopModel ? tabletopModel.all() : null
        console.log('log for newdata', newData)


        var c = 0;

        if (newData == null) {
            console.log('null')
        }
        else {

            for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
                if (newData[i].ID == this.input.value) {
                    c++;
                    //console.log('i', i);
                }

            }
            if (c > 0)
            alert('Your username is: ' + this.input.value);
            //GO TO NEXT PAGE
            else { 
                alert('Invalid login');
            }
        }


    };
```

this is the code
a button exists and when clicked it will run this part

is this right or is there a better solution?

Comment: `how does it automatically redirect to next page?` is really a two-sided question. "How does it redirect to next page?" is up to you - presumably you'd set some state somewhere to say which page it's on. "...automatically..." is that you'd put that state change logic where your alerts are currently

Comment: its okay now
i just used ` this.props.history.push`
                    
and now it works 
Thanks anyway ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways by which you can move to next page

1. If you are using react-router then use history to redirect

`this.props.history.push("/yourPath")`

3. If you are not getting history in props then you can use JS method for redirection

`window.location.href="/yourPath"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.props.history.push` if you're in a class component or `props.history.push` if it's a functional component,
You can also pass state to the page you are redirecting to, like:

```js
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/next-page',
  state: { from: "prev-page" }
})
```

The passed state will be stored in `props.location.state` in next-page,

You can also replace this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
    if (newData[i].ID == this.input.value) {
        c++;
        //console.log('i', i);
    }
}
```

with this:

```js
if(newData.some(currentValue => currentValue.ID === this.input.value)) {
    c++;
    //console.log('i', i);
}
```

Comment: This is great!
Question tho how can I pass the state to multiple pages and not just the next page?

Comment: You mean you want to pass a predefined state to every page you open?

Comment: Yup! Cos it seems that the `state: { from: "prev-page" }` only works for the targeted page in Pathname